# How to find the Data loss cause?

Tags: http, networking, web, memcached

I am working on a application that uses two memcache servers configured as a cluster .
I am currently in a stage of  testing the application , for this sometimes i manually  make one instance of MEmcache down .

Sometimes our network goes Up/down and as a case it sometimes doen't recieve the data , i am in a situation where i am confused whether the data loss is due to Network issues /or making a memcace instance down .

For your information , i am using xmemcached 1.3.8 , ketamamemcachesessionlocator and repcached 2.3 for replication with

Failure Mode off in client .

So i am pretty much sure that there will be no Data loss at all (Correct me if i am wrong )

My question is that , is there any situation  by which i can know that this loss is due to what cause ??

Answer (score 0):

It's memcache. Losing data is what it does. You should never count on it for any sort of persistent storage.

Comment: I also initially thought that it was Memcache , but what gave me a thought is that at the same time i logged into production ,  even the stable application which is running in production didn't gave me that information . So really cant judge that if it was caused due to memcache only .